# How get counts of repeat elements in Array. Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get the count of records for the current day, from the database. The entries in the Firebase Realtime are in timestamp, I parse them using SimpleDateFormat.

But I could not get the count of records, for example, for today's date. Tell me what to do? Thanks

[IMAGE RECORDS IN FIREBASE REALTIME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucW9L.png)

```
private void fetchDataWaterCount() {
    currDate = null;
    String uid = firebaseAuth.getUid();
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        currDate = LocalDate.now().toString();
    }
    waterRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(uid).child("body").child("water");
    waterRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    waterModel = ds.getValue(WaterModel.class);
                    waterArray.add(waterModel);
                    waterModel.setWaterModelList(waterArray);
                    ArrayList listDate = new ArrayList();
                        for (int i = 0; i < waterModel.getWaterModelList().size(); i++) {
                            long dateList = waterModel.getWaterModelList().get(i).getDate();
                            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
                            String dateFormat = formatter.format(new Date(dateList));
                            listDate.add(dateFormat);
                            if(listDate.contains(currDate)){
                                int water_count = (int) listDate.size();
                                drawable = getActivity().getDrawable(R.drawable.circut_progress_bar);
                                progressBar.setProgress(water_count);
                                progressBar.setMax(12);
                                progressBar.setSecondaryProgress(water_count);
                                progressBar.setProgressDrawable(drawable);
                                textViewWaterCount.setText(String.valueOf(water_count));
                                if (water_count >= 12) {
                                    textViewWaterCount.setText("Done");
                                    textViewWaterCount.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen_900));
                                    drawable = getActivity().getDrawable(R.drawable.circut_progressbar_green);
                                    progressBar.setProgressDrawable(drawable);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you verify, that the 2 string dates `currDate` and `dateFormat` are the same at any point in time? There are 2 reasons `listDate.contains(currDate)` would `return false`. There simply is no date that matches OR there is a date that matches but it is formatted incorrectly, because you are just comparing `String`s at this point.

Comment: Why not using a query with `startAt(startOfTheDay)` and `endAt(endOfTheDay)`?

Comment: @avalerio Thank you for you answer. I see at logs that `listDate.contains(currDate)` - `return true`. I've checked format date in the array and in `currDate` . This is same.

Comment: @AlexMamo That's a good idea! I'll try. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know the amount of `WaterModels` that match a specific date then you need to count them as they appear.

You are currently adding every date to the list regardless if it matches the `currDate`, so your count is the total dates not the specific amount of specific dates.

```
//Add this
int dateCount = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < waterModel.getWaterModelList().size(); i++) {
    long dateList = waterModel.getWaterModelList().get(i).getDate();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
    String dateFormat = formatter.format(new Date(dateList));
    listDate.add(dateFormat);


    //Add this
    if(dateFormat == currDate){
             dateCount++;
    }


    //I don't know what your doing here but this will return true
    //if there is at least 1 match. You can't use this to track how many dates
    //match
    if (listDate.contains(currDate)) {
        int water_count = (int) listDate.size();
        drawable = getActivity().getDrawable(R.drawable.circut_progress_bar);
        progressBar.setProgress(water_count);
        progressBar.setMax(12);
        progressBar.setSecondaryProgress(water_count);
        progressBar.setProgressDrawable(drawable);
        textViewWaterCount.setText(String.valueOf(water_count));
        if (water_count >= 12) {
            textViewWaterCount.setText("Done");
            textViewWaterCount.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen_900));
            drawable = getActivity().getDrawable(R.drawable.circut_progressbar_green);
            progressBar.setProgressDrawable(drawable);
        }
    }
}
```

`dateCount` will contain the total amount of Dates that match the `currDate`.